# Prove that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d , P_x\{y\in B\mathopen]0,1]\}=0$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm folowing the proof of corollary 1.8 page 5 of [Mörters - Sample path properties of Brownian motion](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/lecnotes_moerters.pdf).

I want to show that $$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d , P_x\{y\in B\mathopen]0,1]\}=0$$ where $B$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.
We will use the Lévy's theorem that says: $$\mathcal{L}_2(B[0,1])=0 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{almost surely.}$$

- in the first step we will show that $$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^d,  P_x\{y\in B[0,1]\}=0  \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for $\mathcal{L}_2$-almost every } x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$
  for any fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$\begin{eqnarray*}
          \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}P_{y}(x\in B[0,1])dx&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\int_\Omega 1_{\{x\in B[0,1]\}}(\omega)dP_y(\omega)dx\\&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\int_\Omega 1_{B[0,1](\omega)}(x)dP_y(\omega)dx\\&=&\int_\Omega \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}1_{B[0,1](\omega)}(x)dxdP_y(\omega)\hspace{0.5cm} \text{by Tonelli}\\&=&
          \int_\Omega \mathcal{L}_2(B[0,1](\omega))dP_y(\omega)\\&=&
          E_{y}(\mathcal{L}_{2}(B[0,1])=0\\
      \end{eqnarray*}
  so $$P_x\{y\in B[0,1]\}=0  \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for almost every } x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$
  (now how can we get rid of the "for almost every $x$"?).
- in the second step he shows by symmetry of Brownian motion that: (but I don't know where did he use it) \begin{eqnarray*}
          P_{x}(y\in B[0,1])&=&P_{0}(y-x\in B[0,1])\\&=&P_{0}(y-x \in -B[0,1])\\&=&P_{y}(x\in B[0,1])=0\\
      \end{eqnarray*}
- in the third and last step he will get rid of the "for almost every $x$":
  we will show that $\forall \epsilon >0, $ we have almost surely $P_{B(\epsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\}=0$ and we will find the result by sending $\epsilon$ to zero
  \begin{eqnarray*}
          P_{x}\{y\in B\mathopen]0,1]\}&=&P_{x}\{y=B_t / t\in \mathopen]0,1]\}
          \\&=&P_{x}(\bigcup_{\epsilon>0}\{ y=B_t / t\in \mathopen]\epsilon,1]\})\\&=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}P_{x}\{ y=B_t / t\in ]\epsilon,1]\}
          \\&=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}P_{x}\{ y=B_{t+\epsilon} / t\in \mathopen]0,1-\epsilon]\}
          \\&=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}P_{x}\{ y=B_{t+\epsilon}-B_\epsilon +B_\epsilon / t\in \mathopen]0,1-\epsilon]\}\\&=&
          \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}P_{x}\{ y=B_t+B_\epsilon / t\in \mathopen]0,1-\epsilon]\}\\&=&
           \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\lim}P_{B\epsilon}\{ y=B_t+x / t\in \mathopen]0,1-\epsilon]\}\\&=&
           \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\lim}\int_\Omega 1_{\{y=B_t+x / t\in \mathopen]0,1-\epsilon]\}}(\omega)dP_{B(\epsilon)}(\omega)\\&=&
  \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} E_xP_{B(\epsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\}.
      \end{eqnarray*}

  I didn't get how he arrived to the last equation: $\underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\lim}\int_\Omega 1_{\{y=B_t+x / t\in \mathopen]0,1-\epsilon]\}}(\omega)dP_{B(\epsilon)}(\omega)=
  \underset{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{\lim} E_xP_{B(\epsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\}$.

Comment: Instead of writing your interpretations of the proof, can you simply say what is the first place in the proof that seems unclear?

Comment: sorry for not being clear , i add the question

Comment: Most of your discussion is about $B[0, 1]$, but you start with $B\mathopen]0, 1]$ (title and body).  Was that intentional?  (At first I thought it was a typo, but there's an explicit `\mathopen`.) \\ Please use subscripts rather than `\underset` when appropriate: e.g., `\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}`, not `\underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\lim}`.  I have edited accordingly.  (If you were doing this to bypass effects like $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}$, then the appropriate way is to use `\limits`: $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}$ `\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}`.)

Comment: @sara : I don't see this "last equation" in the lecture notes. Again, instead of writing your interpretations of the proof, can you simply say what is the first place in the actual proof in the notes that seems unclear?

Comment: @LSpice i'll do it , thank you

Comment: @IosifPinelis the proof is not detailed , he find directly $P_{x}\{y\in B]0,1]\}=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} P_{x}\{ y\in B[\epsilon,1]\}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} E_xP_{B(\epsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\}$

Comment: i couldn't arrive to the $E_x$

Comment: In your penultimate comment, $[0,1]$ should be replaced by $[0,1-\epsilon]$, as in the notes. Then the corresponding expression will be obtained by Theorem 1.2 (Strong Markov property in the notes).